# (django)I created a todo app in django but everytime I update the task. It creates a new object

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

It creates new object everytime I update the task.
I tried alot but it still does mot work correctly .Help me please
Models.py contains only a charfield for title, boolean field for task status(task completed or not completed) , a dattime field with auto_add_now=True and an str function returning title

```
def index(request):
task = Task.objects.all().order_by('-created_on')
form= TaskForm()
if request.method=='POST':
    form= TaskForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    return redirect ('/')
return render(request('task/list.html',{'task':task,'form':form})

def update_task(request,pk):
    task =Task.objects.get(id=pk)
    form= TaskForm(instance= task)
    if request.method=='POST':
        form= TaskForm(request.POST,instance=task)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect('/')
    return render(request,'task/update_task.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def update_task(request,pk):
   task =Task.objects.get(id=pk)
   form= TaskForm(instance= task)
   if request.method=='POST':
       form= TaskForm(request.POST,instance=task)
       if form.is_valid():
           f = form.save(commit=False)
           f.save()
       return redirect('/')
    return render(request,'task/update_task.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be the problem with your primary key if it isn't the AutoField() or is not defined. As you could be changing your primary key in the form.

Another approach is you could check out which fields are changed, then manually change their values in the task instance.

```
   def update_task(request,pk):
       task =Task.objects.get(id=pk)
       form= TaskForm(instance= task)
       if request.method=='POST':
           form= TaskForm(request.POST,instance=task)
           if form.is_valid():
               if 'some_field_in_task' in form.changed_data:
               task.some_field_in_task = form.cleaned_data['some_field_in_task']
               task.save()
         return redirect('/')
       return render(request,'task/update_task.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Okay!! just for a hit and trial.. just change task =Task.objects.get(id=pk) to task =Task.objects.get(pk=pk)
Thats pretty much I always used to update. Or u could try using Forms instead of ModelForms.

Comment: Still does not work ..but the same code works in dennis Ivy's tutorial :") on YouTube.

Comment: I added a button to delete the task but it also does not work..it does nothing..i guess its not able to make changes to database other than creating new objects :") ...

Comment: I could help you if you share the code.. Or best would be you could restart your project, follow the tutorial carefully and with proper understanding of whats going on.

Answer (score 0):

You should post your Models.py here also. The issue seems to come from that, not from the views.py
Your views.py looks pretty good.

Comment: Models.py contains only a charfield for title, boolean field for task status(task completed or not completed) , a dattime field with auto_add_now=True and an str function returning title

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue in my todo app. In my case the problem was that in my "update.html", i had a slash("/") within form action attribute.
Like:

form method="POST" action="**/**">

And actually it was redirecing me do my index view(which creates new tasks) and so creating new task.

To solve the problem, just delete this slash and leave it empty.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this explanation may solve the question, including a sample code of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. I suggest you to edit your answer to add some code example, Have a look here → [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Check urls.py once

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('updateTask/<str:pk>/', views.updateTask, name="updateTask"),
]
```